# How to maximize and minimize a div

Tags: javascript, html

How to maximize and minimize a div? Can I resize div according to as need?

Comment: Damn, that's cryptic.

Comment: Maybe use jQuery UI Dialog?  (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)  It natively supports resizing, and a maximize/minimize effect can be achieved by hiding/showing the dialog, even toggling it with a custom "minimized" version.

Comment: see this are you looking this one :- http://jsfiddle.net/hTVFR/25/

Comment: have you spent at least 10 minutes googling?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you need something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/Qy6Sj/1/

You can view the code in jsfiddle here is the code what I have done created a div with another div inside as title bar and content box

**html**

```
<div id="widnow">
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#widnow{
    width:400px;
    border:solid 1px;
}

#title_bar{
    background: #FEFEFE;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
#button{
    border:solid 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 23px;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#box{
    height: 250px;
    background: #DFDFDF;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Please add the code and an explanation to your answer as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for your suggession

Comment: if there two or more box in div. and want to show one box on complete div. and if again need to same size to be set.

Comment: if there are more boxes in window and each having button with it how can i show one on complete window and other other are in behind that.

Comment: You need multiple div with min and max option ?

Comment: You can change the id to class and give the id unique for each div

Comment: If I am not wrong this is not a right answer to the question as its asked for maximize and minimize as in macintosh or windows where in both height and width changes. the code example here its an accordion!